# How do I tell an iOS device there's no internet connection on the Wifi?

Tags: ipad, ios, wifi, cellular-data

I've setup a WiFi network to allow iOS devices (such as my iPad) to connect to other devices on the local network, but I want to be able to use the 3G functionality on my iPad at the same time to connect to the internet. How can I setup the WiFi so that the iOS device doesn't think there's an internet connection through it?

I've tried setting the DHCP Gateway to 0.0.0.0 but this just seems to confuse the iPad - the spinning circle next to the Wifi network never disappears even though it has an IP address from the DHCP server.

Update:
I was able to set the DHCP Gateway to 0 and the Router entry now appears as blank, but the spinning circle still doesn't disappear.

Update:
Setting the DHCP Gateway to 0 or 0.0.0.0 works fine for Windows, Android and Windows Mobile so I'm beginning to think this is an iOS bug. I've posted a question on the Apple iOS Dev forum [here](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/166472).

Comment: Not sure I understand - if you want to use 3G, why not just turn off Wi-Fi?

Comment: If I understand this correctly you want your iPhone/iPad to connect via WLAN for addresses in your local network and via 3G for all other addresses?

Comment: Basically yes. The addresses in the local network will be discovered using Bonjour, but for anything else we want it to fall back to 3G.

Comment: I think Apple just nixed this ability in iOS 10. I followed all above instructions regarding static IP to a T and still no internet connection through cellular. :( Can anyone still verify this method with iOS 10?

Comment: iOS 10.3.3, haven't been able to make this work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in iOS7 - I set the DHCP Gateway to 0.0.0.0 and the iPad connects with a tickbox rather than leaving the spinning circle.

Comment: is this still working iOS8+ ? thanks

Comment: @3pic – yes it is (Tested on iOS 9 actually) See my answer below

Answer (score 17):

You should define a STATIC address for the WiFi/LAN. (define an correct netmask, and **dont enter any router/gateway address** ). (see the static tab in the @Michiel's screenshot.)

When you done, you can access the computers on WiFi network and you will access the rest of the Internet via 3G.

This is what you looking for?

Comment: I should have been more specific. We want the Wifi to use DHCP so this isn't an option. How can I set the DHCP gateway to a value that the iPad will read as unset?

Comment: @parsley72 Why are you so set on DHCP? Unless there's something I'm missing, it's not going to be of a benefit to you in this situation. By the way, nice answer, @kobame!

Comment: If you don't have DHCP then the iOS device takes about a minute to assign a zeroconfig address. This isn't a good user experience.

Comment: This is the right answer. Set the Static address to the address you received from the DHCP server, leave out the gateway. This is how I do it, works great.

Comment: I'm trying to setup a network on a product to sell to non-technical customers. Asking them to set a static address isn't very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully connect to my Arduino's wifi and still retain access to the web, but I struggled following the instructions from the other questions and comments, so here is my explanation.

---

### TL;DR

1. Connect to Arduino Yun wifi
2. Make note of the DHCP `IP address` and `Subnetmask`
3. And use those values with `Static` IP

### Long Version

There's lots of resources explaining the normal methods of connecting, but this is how to connect from an iOS device and **still retain access to the web** via cell network.

After resetting the Yun's wifi (hold reset button for 6-10 seconds), wait until the device finishes booting and it's wifi network is available.

Connect to the Yun network, and take note of the `IP address` and `Subnet mask` in the info view. Then switch to `Static` IP and enter the aforementioned IP and subnet mask.

You should now be able to connect to the arduino (`arduino.local`) and still access the web.